# In combat, how many creatures can be in a 5 foot square at the end of a turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, creature-size

In D&D 5e, basically all PCs fit in on a 5 foot square. I want to figure out how much that 5 foot square can hold at end of turn by rules as written.

**My first estimation is 3 people.**
Using the rule that allows creatures to use other creatures that are a size category bigger then them as a mount, allows for the situation: A centaur barbarian counts as large for carrying and pushing so with some plate armored fighter on top, duel wielding lances, a half-ling sits on the fighters shoulders, gets us to three.

That is 3, but can we get more?

Comment: Are you asking about at the end of a turn or in mid-turn? Or is this purely theoretical as you can't end your turn by choice in someone else's space?

Comment: @NautArch I was thinking end-of-turn. I will at that to the question.

Comment: @Overthinks: I'm not sure your initial assumption holds that just because a centaur counts as large for carrying and pushing means it can also be a mount for a medium creature. The centaur is still medium size so this doesn't negate the 'mount must be a size category larger" rule.

Comment: I edited your title for clarity and to add the part about being in battle specifically. Does that align with what you are asking?

Comment: Would you like answers to assume a particular answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/163081) - If a creature's turn starts in the same space as another creature, is it required to leave that space before its turn ends? Additionally, you technically say a 5-foot square but I assume you mean a 5-foot cube?

Comment: How long do we have to set up our answer, can it take multiple rounds and any number of allies? Do the creatures have to remain in the same square/cube for an extended amount of time or is even an instant enough time? Can things such as *true polymorph* and *gaseous form* be used?